# Git bash doesn't execute npm install

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, git-bash

I keep getting this error in Git Bash when trying to do an npm install:

```
64 verbose stack Error: command failed
64 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\baseuser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\promise-spawn\index.js:64:27)
64 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28)
64 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1058:16)
64 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:293:5)
65 verbose pkgid app-backend@1.0.1-dev.0
66 verbose cwd C:\work\gitrepo\app-backend
67 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18363
68 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\baseuser\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
69 verbose node v14.18.0
70 verbose npm  v8.0.0
71 error code 1
72 error path C:\work\gitrepo\app-backend
73 error command failed
74 error command C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c npm run build
75 verbose exit 1
```

I have node and npm installed globally and npm install works in Powershell or Windows Command line, but not in Git Bash for some reason. I have them added to PATH variable. I done `npm clear cache -force` but nothing changed.

Removed node, npm, git with git bash and reinstalled them againt, and the error still present.

Answer (score 0):

this issue happened recently to many ppl earlier in the last 2 weeks , it seems like a problem withh package distrepution .

To fix this try cloning your library to different location . going into the packages/dscc-scripts directory and running the build command. You can then point all of the scripts from the package.json dscc-gen made to the packages/dscc-scripts/index.js file. Bit of a hack, but good for the quick fix.